# How to resolve the "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied)" error?

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo, boto3

When I try to generate the credential report, this error pops out

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GenerateCredentialReport operation: User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/freshers is not authorized to perform: iam:GenerateCredentialReport on resource: *
```

How can I fix/resolve this issue?

Comment: You have to add missing permission `iam:GenerateCredentialReport` to the IAM user or role which you use to execute your script.

Comment: Ya, Should I have to check in the AWS?@Marcin

Comment: Yes. You have to go to IAM user or IAM role which you use, and add missing permission(s) in the IAM console. If you have no rights yourself to add such permissions, then have to ask the account's admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to add missing permission `iam:GenerateCredentialReport` to the IAM user or role which is used to execute the boto3 script.

Comment: ya like in the JSON format right? like {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GenerateCredentialReport",
            "iam:GetCredentialReport"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
}

Comment: @Navi Sorry, I would prefer not to share at present.